# How to change Fingerprint in Google Console?

Tags: android, console, sha1, fingerprint

I wonder if we can change the fingerprint in the google console developper without deleting the application?

My problem is that in debug mode the keystore is different so the sha1 too.
I'm on eclipse

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok I found it is possible on [Developers console](https://console.developers.google.com),

Project => API & Auth => IDs

Comment: i don't know anyone didn't mark + on this question during this entire time... it is really very common issue