# Could anyone help me to find settings Google Console

Tags: android, google-developers-console

I know that is stupid question but i realy can't find where i can change SHA1 key of my project...

I found exactly explenation of that what i need in another [SOF question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26123517/how-to-change-fingerprint-in-google-console)

He said that we need following the link and than

```
Project => API & Auth => IDs
```

When i follow the [provided link](https://console.developers.google.com)

i don't see <kbd>API & Auth</kbd> button...

There is screenshot

[image]

Where is this botton?

Why it is hiding from me?)

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Credential screenshot

[image]

**EDIT**

Android key screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press 'credentails' in the left panel.

You can setup and manage your keys here now.

press on `Android key (autocreated...`

Comment: I have already opened `Credential` chapter, but there i also have not found it... I added new screenshot to question could you please tell me where i have to click exactly? Thanks

Comment: i don't know maybe we have different screens , but on my screen there is no any fields where i can put my new SHA1 key... added new screenshot... Could you please tell me where i have to click next? Thanks

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko , press on `Android apps` (in the list below). You will see sha-1

Answer (score 0):

https://console.firebase.google.com/?pli=1

go to this link and create project after that you can find the project datails.

Comment: But i don't want to use firebase... i have alredy used regular google login api

Comment: this link redirect me to libraries ... nothing special just list of libs... could you please explain what did you want to say?

Comment: you want to see the credentials of project in google api console right?

Comment: Exactly I wanted to find settings of ID's in google console